# Android Observable with singleton class

Tags: android, singleton, observable, observer-pattern

I have the following

1. Activity A as an observer
2. Activity B as an observer
3. Singleton class C for media player as an observable. Singleton class is notifying the observers (Activity A & B) when the song is completed. 
   However, only one of the Activity is notified at a time
   e.g.
4. When the application starts, I first go to Activity A and play a song using singleton class C, it is notified when the song is completed
5. When the Application starts for the first time, I first go to Activity B and play a song using singleton class C, it is notified when the song is completed.
6. I press back button in Activity A to go back to main menu and then go to Activity B, only Activity A is notified.
7. I press back button in Activity B to go back to main menu and then go to Activity A, only Activity B is notified.

For scenario 1 & 2, it is ok if only one Activity is notified because other Activity is not opened yet,

For scenario 3 & 4, both Activity is already opened but only the Activity which is opened first is always notified.

Am I missing anything in the code to notify both observers ?

```
public class StartActivity extends ListActivity {
.....

   @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        if (position == 1){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, download.class);
        StartActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }

        if (position + 1 == 2){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, qirath.class);
            StartActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }


}

public class download extends ListActivity implements Observer,
        OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        ......
    private mediaManager player ;
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("download called");

    }
       @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                if (player == null) player = getInstance();
                player.addObserver(this);
        }
    }


public class qirath extends ListActivity implements Observer,
        OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        ......
    private mediaManager player ;
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("qirath called");

    }
       @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                if (player == null) player = getInstance();
                player.addObserver(this);
        }
}

public class mediaManager  extends Observable implements  AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener, OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
    private static mediaManager ourInstance;
    MediaPlayer player =null;
     public static mediaManager getInstance()
    {
        if (ourInstance == null) {
            ourInstance = new mediaManager();
            return ourInstance;
        }
        else {
            return ourInstance;
        }
    }
      void createMediaPlayerIfNeeded() {
        if (player == null) {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            player.setOnErrorListener(this);

        }
        else
            player.reset();
    }
.......
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
        // media player finished current song
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers("c");
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: show some key code will be better to see.

Comment: I have updated with code. Thanks.